# How to set registered_delivery on kannel

Tags: smpp, kannel

I have kannel server. From time to time we missing delivery receipts.

I am trying to find if SMPP registered_delivery is set correctly.

This is how we send the SMS:

```
http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=foo&password=bar&from=$from&to=$to&text=$text&smsc=MOBILE_SEND&dlr-url=$dlrurl&smsc-id=nova&dlr-mask=31
```

We have separate server for sending and receiving.

Config file looks like this:

## send:

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = xxxx
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
# SMSBOX related
smsbox-port = 13001
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
store-type = spool
store-location = "/var/spool/eti_content/"


# SMSC SMPP

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = MOBILE_SEND
host = 10.10.10.10
port = 8000
transceiver-mode = false
smsc-username = "foo"
smsc-password = "bar"
interface-version = 34
system-type = CMT
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
allowed-smsc-id = MOBILE_SEND
throughput = 65.0
max-pending-submits = 25


# SMSBOX SETUP

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13013
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
http-request-retry = 0
http-queue-delay = 30
max-pending-requests = 100000


# SEND-SMS USERS

group = sendsms-user
username = foo
password = bar
#user-deny-ip = ""
#user-allow-ip = ""
concatenation = true
max-messages = 3


# SMS SERVICE Default
# there should be default always
group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "No service specified"
```

## receive:

same file, except different ports and:

```
transceiver-mode = true

...

group = sms-service
keyword = default
get-url = "http://localhost/sms/dlr.php?msisdn=%p&shortcode=%P&time=%t&message=%a"
allowed-receiver-prefix = 2301
catch-all = true
omit-empty = true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check your logs (which is specified in smsc group in kannel config file with log level of 0), you will get the smpp packets sent and recieved here. in "deliver-sm" and "submit-sm" packets you can check registered-delivery.